# How can I disable button of navigation bar and status bar?

Tags: android, statusbar, navigationbar, android-homebutton

I am trying to develop a fullscreen mode app. Now I have set my app as immersive mode that hides every time the status bar and navigation bar, and only shows them when user made a swipe gesture in top/bottom edge of the screen

I think is not possible to disable permanently the status bar and navigation bar but it would be a great solution if I hide as immersive mode and disable all three buttons of navigation bar (Home button, back button and task manager button) although they are showing

**NOTE:** I am developing this app only for Android P and I only need a solution for this version.

To set app in immersive mode I have added to my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in my **MainActivity.kt**:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_INMERSIVE_STICKY)
```

I have been trying to access to UI listener to avoid gestures but failed

```
window.decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {
  //For example hide action
  actionBar.hide()
}
```

and I don't know how to access to navigation bar buttons and disable their actions, also I want to avoid to swipe from top edge and show notifications manager view.

Please some help and suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 09/18/19**

For this I have implemented a kiosk mode in my application.

I made a Launcher Activity that configure all needed for the application and if everything goes well the app run but if not, I show a message warning.

There are two pre-conditions very important for that:

**1.** Device shouldn't have any account in the device (Google account, Samsung account, etc)

**2.** The app should be owner and admin of the device (I will explain later)

**STEPS**

**1. Implement receiver in AndroidManifest**

```
<receiver
                android:name=".security.CustomDeviceAdminReceiver"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

**2. Implement CustomDeviceAdminReceiver**

```
    class CustomDeviceAdminReceiver: DeviceAdminReceiver() {
        companion object {
            fun getComponentName(context: Context): ComponentName {
                return ComponentName(context.applicationContext, CustomDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
```

**3. Create xml folder and a xml file inside it called device_admin_receiver**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

**4. In Launcher Activity do this:**

```
class LauncherActivity : BaseActivity() {

        private var adminComponentName: ComponentName
        private var devicePolicyManager: DevicePolicyManager

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.launcher_activity)

            adminComponentName = CustomDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(this)
            devicePolicyManager = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        }

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            initKioskMode()
        }

        private fun initKioskMode() {
            setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT)
            setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET)
            setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_ADD_USER)
            setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA)

            setKeyGuardEnabled()
        }

        private fun setUserRestriction(restriction: String) = devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(adminComponentName, restriction)

        private fun setKeyGuardEnabled() {
            devicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled(adminComponentName, false)
            setLockTask()
        }

        private fun setLockTask() {
            devicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponentName, arrayOf(packageName))
            startLockTask()
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }

        private fun checkAppDeviceOwnerStatus() {
            if (isAppDeviceOwner() && isAppDeviceActiveAdmin()) initKioskMode()
            else {
                stopLockTask()
                showWarningAdvices()
            }
        }

        private fun isAppDeviceOwner() = devicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(packageName)

        private fun isAppDeviceActiveAdmin() = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponentName)

        private fun showWarningAdvices() {
            adminWarningTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            adminWarningMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
}
```

**5. Made my Activity as Main and Launcher**

```
<activity
        android:name=".screen.main.LauncherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**6. And finally you have to set up your app as device owner and admin device app**

This is made by command line with this ->

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner packageName/path to Admin device file
```

PD: To delete owner profile from device to have to run in terminal:

```
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin packageName/path to Admin device file
```

Aaaaaand that's all!!

Comment: how then user is supposed to exit your app when he wants, if you are going to disable all the ways to do that?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko this is because is not a public app, is for commercial purpose and is not possible to exit from the app

Comment: @TimCastelijns, as i said to Vladyslav is for commercial purpose so is like kiosk mode but I need to do it programmatically, not for mobile settings

Comment: it is not possible. Only kiosk mode can do the trick.

Comment: I saw that I can disable back button overriden onBackPressed() method but home and menu button I am afraid can't, but what about notifications menu @VladyslavMatviienko?

Comment: any way to hide the back button? you can do that with the samsung knox